# the php file does not show any output

Tags: php, html

I used HTML and PH PHP to calculate the normal unit

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Comprehensive FORM CGI program </title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#DDDDDD>
<p>
<!-- The lines above are the standard html header -->

<?php

  // First get the input variables and their values

$A = $_POST['f_A'];

$B = $_POST['f_B'];


$Acomponent = explode(",", $A);
$Bcomponent = explode(",", $B);

$AX = (int)$Acomponent[0];
$AY = (int)$Acomponent[1];
$AZ = (int)$Acomponent[2];
$BX = (int)$Bcomponent[0];
$BY = (int)$Bcomponent[1];
$BZ = (int)$Bcomponent[2];


function dot_product($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ){
$dotproduct = ($AX*$BX+$AY*$BY+$AZ*$BZ);
return($dotproduct);

}

function cross_product($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ){
        
        $i = ($AY*$BZ-$AZ*$BY);
        $j = (-1)*($AX*$BZ-$AZ*$BX);
        $k = ($AX*$BY-$AY*$BX);
        return($i);
        return($j);
        return($k);

}


function norm($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ) {
     
        
        
        $Anorm=sqrt(pow($AX,2)+pow($AY,2)+ pow($AZ,2));
        $Bnorm=sqrt(pow($BX,2)+pow($BY,2)+ pow($BZ,2));
        
        return($Anorm);
        return($Bnorm);

}

function anglebetween($dotproduct,$Anorm, $Bnorm) {
        $angle = acos($dotproduct/($Anorm*$Bnorm));
        return($angle);
}

function normalunitvector($i,$j,$k) {
   
        $crossnorm=sqrt(pow($i,2)+pow($j,2)+ pow($k,2));
        $normaluniti = $i/$crossnorm;
        $normalunitj = $j/$crossnorm;
        $normalunitk = $k/$crossnorm;
        $normalunit = [];
        $normalunit[0] = $normaluniti;
        $normalunit[1] = $normalunitj;
        $normalunit[2] = $normalunitk;
        return($normalunit);
}


dot_product($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ);
cross_product($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ);
norm($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ);
anglebetween($dotproduct,$Anorm, $Bnorm);
normalunitvector($i,$j,$k);

echo($angle);
echo($normaluniti);
echo($normalunitj);
echo($normalunitk);
?>
<p>
<hr>
<p>
</body>
</html>
```

AX, AY, AZ, BX, BY, BZ values were printed very well, but the value of angle, normaluniti, normalunij, normalunitk were not printed.

I don't know why, but I guess there is an error in my function?

```
echo($angle);
echo($normaluniti);
echo($normalunitj);
echo($normalunitk);
```

did not show anything. How can fix this issue?

Comment: Am I not supposed to use two return() in one function?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10700865e29d3b306136ccc7154c9fc8f651afe2 gives many warnings.  What are f_A and f_B supposed to be?

Comment: I think your variables are out of scope.

Comment: @mplungjan f_A and f_B is from another html file. For example there are vector A and vector B. Users will type 2,3,1 and 1,1,1 like this.

Comment: @Zapp oh.... I couldn't think that my variables are out of scope. Is there a reason?

Comment: You called the functions, returned values, but you have NOT assigned the value back to the variables OUTSIDE the functions. (please note that the variables inside a function will no longer be available after the function ends, unless it is set as GLOBAL or something like that)

Comment: @Ken Lee oh.... So I have to declare another variable before the funciton and assign the value of function to it, right?

Comment: @DonghyokLee You declare your variables within the functions (anglebetween and normalunitvector), then you refer to them from outside the function. Declare all those variables above the functions or use the 'global' keyword. There are still other problems with math syntax though.

Comment: @Zapp May I ask you what kind of math syntax error is there?? I just declared all global variables but it show NANANANAN

Comment: Please refer to my suggested answer

Answer (score 1):

1. After execution of the functions , please assign the returned value(s) to local variable(s)
2. For return of multiple values from a single function, please use an array

Hence, please find below a working example :

(For testing, I have added two lines to assign the values of $A and $B, please remove them if you want to apply the values of $_POST)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Comprehensive FORM CGI program </title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#DDDDDD>
<p>
<!-- The lines above are the standard html header -->

<?php

  // First get the input variables and their values

//$A = $_POST['f_A'];
//$B = $_POST['f_B'];

$A = "10,20,30";
$B = "25,100,1000";



$Acomponent = explode(",", $A);
$Bcomponent = explode(",", $B);

$AX = (int)$Acomponent[0];
$AY = (int)$Acomponent[1];
$AZ = (int)$Acomponent[2];
$BX = (int)$Bcomponent[0];
$BY = (int)$Bcomponent[1];
$BZ = (int)$Bcomponent[2];


function dot_product($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ){
//$dotproduct = ($AX*$BX+$AY*$BY+$AZ*$BZ);
//return($dotproduct);
return ($AX*$BX+$AY*$BY+$AZ*$BZ);

}

function cross_product($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ){
        
        $i = ($AY*$BZ-$AZ*$BY);
        $j = (-1)*($AX*$BZ-$AZ*$BX);
        $k = ($AX*$BY-$AY*$BX);
//        return($i);
//        return($j);
//        return($k);

return array($i, $j, $k);
}


function norm($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ) {
     
        
        
        $Anorm=sqrt(pow($AX,2)+pow($AY,2)+ pow($AZ,2));
        $Bnorm=sqrt(pow($BX,2)+pow($BY,2)+ pow($BZ,2));
        
//        return($Anorm);
//       return($Bnorm);
return array($Anorm,$Bnorm);

}

function anglebetween($dotproduct,$Anorm, $Bnorm) {
//        $angle = acos($dotproduct/($Anorm*$Bnorm));
//        return($angle);
return acos($dotproduct/($Anorm*$Bnorm));

}

function normalunitvector($i,$j,$k) {
   
        $crossnorm=sqrt(pow($i,2)+pow($j,2)+ pow($k,2));
        $normaluniti = $i/$crossnorm;
        $normalunitj = $j/$crossnorm;
        $normalunitk = $k/$crossnorm;
      //  $normalunit = [];
      //  $normalunit[0] = $normaluniti;
      //  $normalunit[1] = $normalunitj;
      //  $normalunit[2] = $normalunitk;
      //  return($normalunit);
return array($normaluniti, $normalunitj, $normalunitk);
}




$dotproduct=dot_product($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ);

$array1 = cross_product($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ);


$i=$array1[0];
$j=$array1[1];
$k=$array1[2];


$array2=norm($AX, $AY, $AZ, $BX, $BY, $BZ);

$Anorm=$array2[0];
$Bnorm=$array2[1];


$angle=anglebetween($dotproduct,$Anorm, $Bnorm);


$array3 =normalunitvector($i,$j,$k);

$normaluniti=$array3[0];
$normalunitj=$array3[1];
$normalunitk=$array3[2];



echo " Angle is :". ($angle);
echo "<br>";

echo " Normaluniti is :".($normaluniti);
echo "<br>";

echo " Normalunitj is :".($normalunitj);
echo "<br>";

echo " Normalunitk is :".($normalunitk);
echo "<br>";



?>
<p>
<hr>
<p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using them as local variables inside your functions. Their life begins and ends between the brackets of a function.

Try `echo anglebetween($dotproduct,$Anorm, $Bnorm);` tell me if that works.

If so, you can either store **anglebetween($dotproduct,$Anorm, $Bnorm); in a variable** or just **call the functions**.

Comment: I just followed it and it shows NAN

Comment: Because Anorm and Bnorm are also variables that live inside their functions. Define them outside the functions.